# Why doesn't my scrollpane have scrollbars?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jscrollpane

For some reason I can't get my scrollpane to be displayed within an applet.

```
public void init() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(panel); 
    scrPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout()); 
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrPane); 
    this.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: `scrPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());` - don't play with the layout. The JScrollPane will set the layout itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never display the JFrame that you create!

This:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(scrPane):
this.setVisible(true);   // this != frame
```

is not working because you create a JFrame and then ignore it.

You shouldn't have an applet display a JFrame anyway. If you need to show a separate window, consider showing a JDialog. Better still, why not simply put the JScrollPane in the applet itself?

e.g.,

```
public void init() {
    //JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(panel); 
    scrPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    //  scrPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout()); 
    //  frame.getContentPane().add(scrPane); 

    getContentPane().add(scrPane);

    // this.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I didn't realize this was not the frame.